# "Expected '(' but got identifier" error in Solidity

Tags: solidity

i have this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;
    
    
       
    contract FundMe {
    
        uint256 public minimumUsd = 5;
    
        function Fund() public payable {
              //allow users to send $
             //have a minimum $ sent
             //how do we send ETH to this contract? 
             require(msg.value > minimumUsd, "didn't sent enough ETH") ; //1 ETH=1e18=1000000000000000000 wei //the "require" keyword is a checker
              //revert=undo any actions that have been done, and send the remaining gas back   
            
              
              function getPrice public { 
    
    
                 }
    
              
              function getConversionRate() public {} 
    
    
              function getVersion() public view returns(uint256){
                 return AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306).version();
              }                                                                     
    
        }
            
    
    }
```

and Solidity gives me this error:

```
ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
  --> FundMe.sol:22:20:
   |
22 |           function getPrice public { 
   |                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Why? I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as correct answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your `getPrice()` function is missing the parentheses after the name.

```
 function getPrice public { 


         }
```

Should be:

```
 function getPrice() public { 


         }
```

Also, for future reference you can find out where the error is coming from by looking at your error message. `FundMe.sol:22:20: | 22`  This means your error is coming from that line in your file.